# elementary row operations

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-groups

We know that the elementary row operations generate the general linear group. Suppose that we have a subset of elements of a given general linear group. Is it possible to generate given general linear group via a finite set of elementary row operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends upon the field over which the group is defined.  If you look at general linear groups $\operatorname{GL}(n,q)$ over a field of finite order $q$, then the group is itself finite, so there are only finitely many elementary row operations to begin with.

But consider the general linear group $G = \operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{Q})$ over the rationals $\mathbb{Q}$.  Then $G$ has the multiplicative group $\mathbb{Q}^{\ast}$ of non-zero rationals as a homomorphic image (via the determinant), and $\mathbb{Q}^{\ast}$ is not finitely generated, so $G$ cannot be finitely generated.

Comment: I have a subset of finite group GL(3,2). May you give more details on this statement: " there are only finitely many elementary row operations to begin with".? Actually I have a subset including 6 elements of GL(3,2), my observations show that if I use one or more  elementary row operation for one or two elements of my set, I can construct other elements.

Comment: I just meant that since the group $\operatorname{GL}(n,q)$ is finite, it contains only a finite number of elementary matrices.  (An elementary row operation is just a multiplication by an elementary matrix.)  Since the elementary matrices generate $\operatorname{GL}(3,2)$, all your matrices are products of them and their inverses.  In general, a subgroup need not actually contain any elementary matrices (except the identity), but its elements will be products of them.